# Classifying an input from Java Code while Loading model only once

Tags: rapidminer

I'm developing an app which uses RapidMiner for classification. I train the classifier time to time (e.g. daily) but I use the classifier in very high rate (250 per sec).
For this purpose, I created two Processes using RM GUI. First one trains the classifier and saves it into a model file while the second one uses it for classification.

In the second process I load the model file which the first process creates. This made it very slow since it seems that the process loads it every time I want to classify an input.
You can see the second process in the following picture:
[image]
<sub>(source: [shiaupload.ir](http://www.shiaupload.ir/images/49702023985911120612.png))</sub>

What's the more smart way of doing this?

P.S. I think a solution is to create another process which only loads the created classifier only once and then give it to ApplyModel subprocess as another input. But I didn't find a solution for doing so in Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already discussed and solved [here](http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php/topic,5222.0.html).